# SQL to get notifications for chat

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a chat with the following SELECT:

```
SELECT CLI.id, CLI.nome, CLI.senha, CLI.email, CLI.cpf, CLI.celular,
  CLI.data_nasc, CLI.genero, CLI.data_cadastro, CLI.status, CLI.id_socket, 
  MAX(ATEN.mensagem) AS mensagem, COUNT(ATEN.mensagem) AS novas_mensagens, 
  SUM(COMP.valor) AS valor_total, COMP.data AS ultima_compra, 
  ARQ.nome AS foto, ATEN.data_mensagem, ATEN.mensagem_visualizada

FROM ut_clientes AS CLI

LEFT JOIN ut_compras AS COMP ON COMP.id_cliente = CLI.id
LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS ARQ ON ARQ.id_tipo = CLI.id AND ARQ.tipo = 'ut_clientes'
LEFT JOIN ut_atendimentos AS ATEN ON ATEN.id_usuario_envio = CLI.id

WHERE ATEN.id_usuario_recebido = 59163
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ATEN.id_usuario_recebido
        FROM ut_atendimentos AS ATEN2

    WHERE ATEN2.id_usuario_envio = ATEN.id_usuario_envio 
    AND ATEN2.data_mensagem > ATEN.data_mensagem
)
GROUP BY ATEN.id_usuario_envio
ORDER BY ATEN.data_mensagem DESC
```

The data I receive is populating my view:
http://prntscr.com/jmkkpq

I am implementing the notifications and the COUNT that I execute is not coming correct and I would like to know how to implement COUNT correctly, so that every time the user updates the page, SQL will fetch the COUNT of new messages in the database, which were not read.

My table: http://prntscr.com/jmkde8

Thank's guys!

Comment: You can add a flag field on your table for read status and make a function to get the messages by some sort of data

Comment: by saying " every time the user updates the page" you mean when user insert a new message? is that right? if so, you could use a trigger on Insert or update, whenever a new message is inserted, the trigger will do an action by your choice, which is in your case the count of the new messages. However, you would need a column to store the status of the message (read/unread), to be used within the count query.

Answer (score 0):

Can u write the field as a subselect instead left join, like this...

```
SELECT 
    CLI.id, 
    CLI.nome, 
    CLI.senha,
    ...
    (SELECT COUNT(mensagem) FROM ut_atendimentos WHERE id_usuario_envio = CLI.id) AS novas_mensagens,
    ...
FROM ut_clientes AS CLI
```